# Interstitial vs AppOpenAds android

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

Can someone explain as I can't seems to find a proper post about why use Interstitial or AppOpen ad for fullscreen impression exclusively?

I have read google doc, guidelines and already have experience implementing both types of ads, however why shouldn't I just use Interstitial everywhere where I need fullscreen ad including initial loading and vice versa why shouldn't I use appOpen for transitioning?

Will my app be banned by google if I will show appOpen between nav destinations? Should I prefer certain type for maximizing revenue? Is there any technical difference s in caching/requesting/showing ads.

I just don't understand need in having 2 types of fullscreen ads in my apps as well as I can't find proper discussion about why should I prefer one of them or being unreplaceable one by another.

Answer (score 0):

Interstitial vs AppOpenAds android
AppOpenAds use when user pause an app then come back in the app so app open ad show while on the other hand Interstitial add are typically displayed at natural transition points in the flow of an app, such as between activities.

Comment: Yes, you are right and thats exactly what is written in documentation. But the question is why, they are both functionally full screen ads.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the user interface (UI) is slightly different. When I implement the open app ad, it does not completely cover the screen (the top approximately 20% is not covered), and there is a button that needs to be pressed to remove the ad, as opposed to an interstitial ad, which covers the entire screen. However, I do not see much of a difference between the two types, as you mentioned.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).